# Virtualbox debugging -- g: error: The VM is already running

Tags: debugging, operating-system, kernel, virtualbox, osdev

I'm trying to debug an operating system that I am developing.

When I start up the VM machine with `VirtualBoxVM --startvm "X" --debug` the VM starts paused, but when I execute the 'g' command to continue execution I get this error:

```
g: error: The VM is already running
```

But when I start my virtual machine without `--debug` , everything works fine, but I can't debug.
Why does that error message appear?
The VM starts stopped, so the message doesn't make sense and it doesn't allow me to debug my OS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe "paused" isn't the same thing as "stopped". To unpause the VM, press Host+P (the host key is by default Ctrl)